# how I know if client received or no

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, serversocket, java-websocket

I have this code for client

```
class CCLI {


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
          CCLI ccli = new CCLI() ;
      BufferedReader inFromUser =
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
      InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
      byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
      byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
      String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
      sentence = ccli.reversed(sentence) ;

      sendData = sentence.getBytes();
      DatagramPacket sendPacket =
      new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 8888);
      clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

      DatagramPacket receivePacket =
      new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);


      clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

      Thread.sleep(30);

      String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());



      if (modifiedSentence.contains(" ")){

      System.out.println("Lost ");
      }

      else
      {

      System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);

      }

      }
      }
```

I want know how I check if the client received some thing or no , from server because I want but timer for 30ms if the client not received any thing it mean the PKT loss !

Comment: Let the client send "yes, I received the packed"

Comment: Datagram protocol generally must be prepared to lost some packets (or changed order). This communication is core of Your datagram protocol. Get paper, pencil, and draw logic in your project

Comment: How I know if ( clientSocket.receive(receivePacket) ; ) has a value or not ?